# Run a jUnit test with java.RuntimeException

Tags: java, junit, jboss-arquillian

I got something like this:

StudentBean.java

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Override
public Boolean addStudent(Student s) {
try{
//  Student s1 = new Student(10,"asd", "asd"); //this was for testing
    em.persist(s);
    em.flush();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

    return true;
}
```

Then I got the Student.java with this constructor:

```
public Student(Integer studentId, String firstName, String lastName) {
    this();
    this.studentId = studentId;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

And I got a UTest.java class for testing the functions...
There I got this:

```
 @Test public void testAddStudent() { 
      StudentBean sb = new StudentBean();
      Student s1 = new Student(4, "Ognjen", "Car");
      System.out.println(s1.toString()); //it does not print anything

      Boolean s = sb.addStudent(s1); 

      assert (s == true); 
      // fail("Not yet implemented"); 
  }
```

When I run the tests, it shows this error, and I simply cannot find an answer to it, pls help

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:166)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:103)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:162)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:166)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:103)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.ManagerBuilder.create(ManagerBuilder.java:77)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:62)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:162)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptor/api/Descriptor
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.SecurityActions$1.run(SecurityActions.java:188)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.SecurityActions$1.run(SecurityActions.java:185)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.SecurityActions.getConstructor(SecurityActions.java:184)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:158)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.Reflections.createInstance(Reflections.java:122)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.createExtensions(ManagerImpl.java:440)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fireProcessing(ManagerImpl.java:375)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.<init>(ManagerImpl.java:100)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.api.Descriptor
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 59 more
```

Here is also a picture

[printed screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPHbQ.png)

Comment: Looks like you're missing a Class org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptor/api/Descriptor in your Deployment... do you use Maven for Dependency-Management? If yes, what does your pom.xml look like for arquillian?

Comment: I dont use Maven at all, and how to add that class?

Comment: If this is meant to be a *UnitTest* (in contrast to a *module test* executed with JUnit) then you should replace the EntityManager with a *test double*. The best Way to create such test double is by using a *Mocking Framework) like *Mockito* (or similar).

Comment: to replace the EM with a test double? Can u explain it to me? And is it possible to do it just with arquillian?

Comment: Add the jar containing org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptor/api/Descriptor to your classpath. Can't really tell you what jar that is exactly, we're using Maven for that ;)

Comment: is it possible to use only arquillian?